# How can I set up SignalR Hub Dependency Injection in ASP.NET 5 (vNext)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, signalr, asp.net-core

Trying to do dependency injection into my SignalR Hub class using the SignalR-Server which is part of ASP.NET 5 ([repo](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Server)). I tried to figure this out from the tutorial at [this link](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/advanced/dependency-injection) but I can't seem to identify how I can do this given that `GlobalHost` is no longer available. Here's what I'm trying to do:

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSignalR();
    services.AddSingleton<IState, State>();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseSignalR();
}
```

**MyHub.cs**

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public IState State { get; set; }

    // SignalR accepts this parameterless ctor
    public MyHub()
    {
    }

    // SignalR won't use this because it has a parameter
    public MyHub(IState state)
    {
        State = state;
    }
}
```

How can I get [SignalR-Server](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Server) to use the `MyHub(IState state)` constructor injecting the required dependencies?

Comment: I haven't done DI on SignalR using ASP.NET 5, but I've done DI in 4.6 and I got it working without using `GlobalHost` at all. I will post the configuration once I get on a computer with Visual Studio. Cheers!

Comment: Awesome! That sounds like it could help. Post what you have and I can try to adapt it for ASP.NET 5 and the built in IOC container. Thanks!

Comment: I answered this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661041/signalr-net-client-invoke-throws-an-exception/50964870#50964870 with no singleton magic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to resolve this by adding my `State` class as a Singleton for `IState` in `Startup.ConfigureServices`, and then making a `ServiceProvider` property publicly available on my Startup.cs class. From there, I was able to `GetRequiredService` within the constructor of my SignalR Hub class. It isn't the ideal solution and hopefully I'll be able to adjust this to use constructor/property injection as the platform reaches RC.

Here's my code:

**Startup.cs**

```
public static IServiceProvider __serviceProvider;

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSignalR();
    services.AddSingleton<IState, State>();
    __serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseSignalR();
}
```

**MyHub.cs**

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public IState State { get; set; }

    public MyHub()
    {
        State = (IState) Startup.__serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(typeof (IState));
    }

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        State.Clients = Clients;
        State.Groups = Groups;
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
}
```

In this way, I was able to set properties and call methods on `IState` implementing objects from within `MyHub`, allowing me to persist my app state in memory.

Comment: What about the issue on [SignalR dependency injection using Ninject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57222574/signalr-dependency-injection-using-ninject#comment100955421_57222574)? Any idea about that? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3):

the best way (for Asp.Net 5) create a custom resolver to DefaultDependencyResolver that receives IServiceProvider:

```
 public class CustomSignalRDependencyResolver : DefaultDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public CustomSignalRDependencyResolver(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public override object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        var service = _serviceProvider.GetService(serviceType);

        return service ?? base.GetService(serviceType);
    }


}
```

Then on StartUp class

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

         services.AddSingleton<IState, State>();

        //... other services


        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = new CustomSignalRDependencyResolver(services.BuildServiceProvider());

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Now, I used [Autofac](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/signalr.html), which I am not sure it has ASP.NET 5 integration yet. But if(for now) only target .NET 4.6, you should be fine.

I just published [this repository](https://github.com/radu-matei/SignalRDependencyInjection) which contains a basic project setup with SignalR and Autofac for dependency injection.

Now, I did the dependency injection setup in order to achieve the following:

- be able to inject dependencies into my hub
- be able to get the context for my hubs in order to send to clients from outside the hub without using `GlobalHost` (which is no longer available in .NET 5, but also shouldn't be used since it's a static global object)

I hope you manage to setup your project (even though I don't think you will be able to keep `DNX` in your build options since `Autofac` doesn't have the library .NET 5 ready yet.

I hope this helps! Best of luck!

https://github.com/radu-matei/SignalRDependencyInjection

EDIT: If you want to use NInject (and build your own dependency resolver if you want to target `DNX`, you can follow this repository from the official guys from SignalR  (actually from the guy who wrote SignalR):

https://github.com/DamianEdwards/NDCLondon2013/tree/master/DependencyInjection

In this demo they use NInject to create their own dependency resolver, so you shouldn't have any problems targeting `DNX` if you have NInject libraries.

UPDATE: After reading a little about Dependency Injection in `ASP.NET 5`, it seems that it is done in an unified manner. [If you haven't had a look at this article, I recommend it, even though it doesn't specifically show `SignalR` DI.](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-mvc6/)

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like I can't set the `Resolver` property in SignalR-Server either! :( I had tried it before I came here too. Back to the drawing board, I guess. Thanks though!

Comment: Updated the answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: Also, this [link seems  to explain DI in vNEXT](https://robinsedlaczek.wordpress.com/2014/11/22/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-vnext/)

Answer (score 0):

I have simply made constructor with dependencies. For example, I need my `IUnitOfWork` instance (which was configured in startup) in hub. That is working code

```
[HubName("receipts")]
public class ReceiptsHub : Hub
{
    public IUnitOfWork<string> UnitOfWork { get; set; }

    public ReceiptsHub(IUnitOfWork<string> unitOfWork) : base()
    {
        UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're very close. You just need:

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    readonly IState _state;

    public MyHub(IState state)
    {
        _state = state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 5 you can directly resolve the `IServiceProvider` and later you can have the required service. Please check the below codes:

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public IState State { get; set; }
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    public MyHub(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider=serviceProvider;
        State = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IState>();
    }

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        State.Clients = Clients;
        State.Groups = Groups;
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
}
```